# How to get the "number prefix" to be used in a function? (evil mode)

Tags: evil

With emacs evil-mode, you can use number prefixes before commands (like in vim).  For example `10j` goes 10 lines down.  I am trying to define a custom function which can make use of these "number prefixes" (if that's the right terminology).  How do I capture that prefix in the form of an elisp variable?